# How to concatenate columns in a for loop

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have series of prediction created from each loop. In the end, I want to vertically concatenate them into one data frame. This is the way I did it:

```
pred_list=[]

for i in range (80, 0, -1):
    train_X, train_y = train[:, :-n_features], train[:, -i]
    test_X, test_y = test[:, :-n_features], test[:, -i]

    model = Sequential()
    model.add(LSTM(50, input_shape=(train_X.shape[1], train_X.shape[2])))
    model.add(Dense(1))
    model.compile(loss='mse', optimizer='adam')
   
    # fit network
    history = model.fit(train_X, train_y, epochs=5, batch_size=50)

    # make a prediction
    yhat = model.predict(test_X)
    prediction = pd.DataFrame(yhat, columns=['predicition{}'.format(i)])
    pred_list.append(prediction)

final_prediction=pd.concat(pred_list)
```

However, the final_prediction does not concatenate prediction1, prediction2, prediction3 into columns. It creates pattern like waterflow. My output is like below (assume I have only 3 samples in each prediction):

| prediction1 | prediction2 | predicition3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0.3 | nan | nan |
| 0.01 | nan | nan |
| 0.2 | nan | nan |
| nan | 0.004 | nan |
| nan | 0.3 | nan |
| nan | 0.1 | nan |
| nan | nan | 0.12 |
| nan | nan | 0.2 |
| nan | nan | 0.01 |

What I want:

| prediction1 | prediction2 | predicition3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0.3 | 0.004 | 0.12 |
| 0.01 | 0.3 | 0.2 |
| 0.2 | 0.1 | 0.01 |

Where did I do wrong in my codes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
a = 0 # for rows or 1 for columns
final_prediction=pd.concat(pred_list, axis = a)
```